# ¿ como hacer que los datos de un servicio web se repitan en una llamada de ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function RealizaConsultaNotificacion(operacion, pStringJson) {


$.ajax({
    timeout: 60000,
    url: 'http://74.208.98.86:7070/OriginacionWS',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: pStringJson,
    success: function (data) {
        var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data1[0].estatus == "0") {
            $("#lblNoNotificaciones").html("0");
            $("#AnimatedBellNoti").removeClass("icon-animated-bell");
            $("#lblDscNotificaciones").html("");
            $("#lblDscNotificaciones").append("<i class='ace-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle'>" + " " + "No hay notificaciones recientes para mostrar" + "</i>");
            $("#LinkNotifications").hide();
            //$("#lstNotificacionesMenuPanelS").append("<li><a href='#'><div class='clearfix'><span class='pull-left'><i class='btn btn-xs no-hover btn-success fa fa-line-chart' style='width: 25px; height: 20px;'></i>" + data1[0].desc + "</span><span class='pull-right badgeNoti badge-info'></span></div></a></li>");

        } else if (data1[0].estatus == "-1") {
            console.log("hubo un error en las notificaciones");
        } else {

            var conter = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { // total de las notificaciones

                if (data1[i].estado == "1") { // si la notificacion es nueva..
                    conter++

                    $("#lblNoNotificaciones").html(conter);
                    $("#AnimatedBellNoti").addClass("icon-animated-bell");
                    $("#lblDscNotificaciones").html("");
                    $("#lblDscNotificaciones").append("<i class='ace-icon fa fa-asterisk'>" + " " + "Tienes" + " " + conter + " " + " notificaciones" + "</i>");

                    switch (data1[i].tipomensaje) { // tipo de mensaje como advertencia, informativo etc..
                        case "1":
                            $("#lstNotificacionesMenuPanelS").append("<li><div class='clearfix'><span class='pull-left'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='width:22px;height:17px;color:white;background-color:green;border-radius:7px;'></i>" + " " + data1[i].mensaje + "</span></div></li>");
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            $("#lstNotificacionesMenuPanelS").append("<li><div class='clearfix'><span class='pull-left'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' style='width:22px;height:17px;color:white;background-color:rgba(195, 2, 2, 0.71);border-radius:7px;'></i>" + " " + data1[i].mensaje + "</span></div></li>");
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            $("#lstNotificacionesMenuPanelS").append("<li><div class='clearfix'><span class='pull-left'><i class='fa fa-info' style='width:22px;height:17px;color:white;background-color:blue;border-radius:7px;'></i>" + " " + data1[i].mensaje + "</span></div></li>");
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            $("#lstNotificacionesMenuPanelS").append("<li><div class='clearfix'><span class='pull-left'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' style='width:22px;height:17px;color:white;background-color:yellow;border-radius:7px;'></i>" + " " + data1[i].mensaje + "</span></div></li>");
                            break;
                    }
                } else {

                    $("#AnimatedBellNoti").removeClass("icon-animated-bell");
                    $("#lblDscNotificaciones").html("");
                    $("#lblDscNotificaciones").append("<i class='ace-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle'>" + " " + "No hay notificaciones recientes para mostrar" + "</i>");
                    $("#LinkNotifications").hide();
                    $("#LinkClearNotifications").hide();

                }
            }
            return 
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Algo salio mal");
    },
    async: false
});

return;
```

}

// mi duda es cuando esta función la vuelvo asincrona, osea que se este refrescando cada cierto, me trae datos, pero el problema, es que me esta encimando los datos cada que se esta ejecutando.

Comment: Quisiera unas aclaraciones. Tienes un request (ajax) que ejecutas varias veces y dentro del código de "llamada(request) exitoso" cambias varios objetos del documento, tu problema es que cada vez que llega la respuesta te vuelve a cambiar los objetos del documento, mi pregunta entonces es ¿por qué llamas varias veces el ajax?

Comment: Por que eso se estara ejecutando cada 10 segundos, por ejemplo, esta llamada es para pintar unas notficaciones que me envian un servicio web, entonces yo solo voy a pintar en un "0" el total de las notificaciones nuevas osea en el if(data[i].estado) si el estado es "1" // osea que es nueva, entonces pinto la notificacion y tambien el tipo de notificacion, el problema es cuando en la primera llamada, trae los resultados bien y los pinta el pex es cuando la vuelve hacer llamada me va atraer a traer los mismos y me los encima.

Comment: aaah, a eso te refieres con "me los encima" pues es que no estas reemplazando el contenido de los objetos estas simplemente agregando (append) mas, lo que tienes que hacer es reemplazarlos, si los objetos fueran inputs utiliza el metodo `val()` este asigna el valor de los inputs y si fueran otra cosa (div, span, etc) utiliza el método `html()` este cambia el contenido de los elementos html

Comment: ojo que el método `html()` cambia el contenido y lo asigna como un string, si fueses a agregar objetos html, como en el caso en que agregas `<i>` puedes hacer un `empty().append()` o más correcto aún, podrías referenciar el icono en vez del padre del icono